# PHP/MYSQL- Accepting data into aray and using for-loop counter

Tags: php, mysql

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)))  {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]); 
    echo "<br>"; 

    for($i=0; $i<=600000; $i+=30){
        if($row[0] == $i){
         echo $row[1]." has reached level one <br>";
        }
    }
}
```

The code above accepts data (`id`, `name`) from the database into an array.
I'm having problem with the `$row[1]`, i want it to read the `id`(auto-increment) from 1st-id. It currently picks up data from 3oth-id because of the for-loop and IF-statement assignment operator. I have tried using "reset()" it not working. All i want is for the `$row[]` to start reading ascending from the 1st id while the for loop and if statement remains there. Anticipating help please, been on this for over 24 hours

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Maybe your query needs `ORDER BY id`?